# DHT11 Adafruit Library: Is this parameter necessary?

Tags: c++, arduino

See: https://github.com/adafruit/DHT-sensor-library/blob/master/DHT.h

In DHT.H the constructor initializes the parameter count=6

```
DHT(uint8_t pin, uint8_t type, uint8_t count=6);
```

In DHT.cpp I don't see the variable used anywhere. It only mentions:

```
// Note that count is now ignored as the DHT reading algorithm 
// adjusts itself base on the speed of the processor.

_maxcycles = microsecondsToClockCycles(1000);
```

How exactly is this variable being utilized at any moment?

Comment: Are you asking what is `count` used for now?

Comment: Yes, Barry was able to clarify that for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How exactly is this variable being [utilized] at any moment?

It's not.

It's "ignored as the DHT reading algorithm adjusts itself base *[sic]* on the speed of the processor."

We can see in [this commit](https://github.com/adafruit/DHT-sensor-library/commit/9d7a9da8ae6cc5f6b6dd5be62d787f779e640a2a) that this wasn't the case in a previous version of the code.

> Is this parameter necessary?

Presumably the interface has been maintained for binary stability.

This is perfectly normal and good. If the header file had any useful documenting comments they would point out that `count` is now vestigial.

Comment: Thank you, that's a perfect explanation!

Comment: @Tamburillac: I try :)

Comment: Can you tell me a bit about this binary stability? Wouldn't it be wise to remove the parameter for simplicities sake?

Comment: @Tamburillac: It's a _lot_ more simple in the grand scheme of things not to. Otherwise your library is no longer compatible with any application using it; you have to release a whole new version and ensure that applications that use the new header don't link to the old library. You don't want to go changing the public interface of a library unless you _really_ need to. For the sake of a single `uint8_t`, it's a lot easier to just ignore the argument.

Comment: Interesting thought, I'll keep that in mind (: Thanks again.